# How do you shell into an Alpine/git container?

Tags: git, docker, alpine-linux

How do you shell into this image?

https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/git

I tried:

```
docker pull alpine/git
docker run -it --rm alpine/git /bin/sh
```

but get

```
git: '/bin/sh' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to override the entry point (which is `git`). Otherwise, command line arguments are interpreted as arguments to `git`.

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh alpine/git
```

Comment: also see https://github.com/alpine-docker/git/issues/8 & https://github.com/alpine-docker/git/pull/10 ; tl;dr it's the docker image not adhering to the official guidelines from https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency